# How can I serialize a class to XML using Windows Phone 8 SDK?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, windows-phone-8, serializable

I've got one attribute (_XMLPlaylist) that I want to serialize in a XML-file likeshown in the code:

```
private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _Playlist.Pl_Name = tb_Name.Text.ToString();
        _XMLPlaylist.Playlists.Add(_Playlist);

        IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(StudiCast.Resources.AppResources.Playlists, FileMode.CreateNew, isoStore))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(isoStream))
            {
                var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLPlaylist));
                ser.Serialize(writer, _XMLPlaylist);
                writer.Close();
            }
            isoStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

The Type XMLPlaylist looks as follows:

```
class XMLPlaylist
{
    public XMLPlaylist()
    {
        Playlists = new List<Playlist>();
    }
    public List<Playlist> Playlists;
}
```

And the class Playlist like that:

```
 class Playlist
{
    public Playlist()
    {
        Casts = new List<Cast>();
    }

    public string Pl_Name;
    public List<Cast> Casts;
}
```

'Cast' owns two strings. In .NET 4 I used the keyword [Serializable] in front of the class's name but there isn't the [Serializable]-attribute anymore.

Need fast Help please!

Edit:
Error at 'var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLPlaylist));':

In System.InvalidOperationException an unhandled error of type "System.Xml.Serialization.ni.dll" occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XmlSerializer can serialize only public classes - make your class XMLPlaylist public (also all properties/classes you want to serialize - so Playlist should be public as well).

Comment: Oh my god, that's it. Thanks a lot. I've tried almost everything, but not this. Again, thanks a lot.