# use isolate storage to save items in observablecollection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, observablecollection, isolatedstorage

I've created an app, everything done except save data when close app. In this app I use 2 ObservableCollections which is something like

```
public ObservableCollection<item1> list1 { get; private set; }
public ObservableCollection<item2> list2 { get; private set; }
```

Each item1 and item2 contains some element (string, int, colors ...)

Can I use a simple solution to use isolated setting to save 2 collections and read them when the app starts? I've searched Google but can't find an exact solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2709055/2382032

Comment: use the Add, Save and TryGetValue methods of the [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(v=vs.105).aspx) object

Comment: [walkthrough for using IsolatedStorageSettings in windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769510(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: You can do it like WillNewton had said or serialize to own file. Here are some questions and answers: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17515298/2681948), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242642/how-can-i-serialize-a-class-to-xml-using-windows-phone-8-sdk) which may help.